# Facing Issue with $(window) on scroll when move to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am facing issue with $(window).on 'scroll' event.
It works fine in one page, but it keeps running even when I go to another page.I destroy it in ngOnDestroy() but it's still running

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.onScrollEvent = $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        console.log('scroll: ');
      });
     }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.onScrollEvent) {
          this.onScrollEvent.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up jQuery and Angular which is bad practice first of all. Also `.on()` method does not return a subscription. Instead you would have to use `.off()` method in jQuery.

Either way, I suggest you use Angular's HostListener decorator in your component. This will only be active if the component is active:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
  console.log("We're scrolling!");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz example of the code where you're encountering the issue